# django check user groups in forms

Tags: django, forms, usergroups

I have a form defined from a model class.
Depending from the user group of the logged in user, some fields should be read-only.
I tried with the 'request.user.groups.values_list'. But this is not working, error message: 'global name 'request' is not defined'

class gwagen1Form(forms.ModelForm):

```
class Meta:
    model = gwagen1
    fields = ('gwnummer', 'wk_auftrag', 'model', 'vorbesitzer', 'typ', 'verwendung',
              'kennzeichen', 'hsn_tsn', 'km_stand', 'repartur_kosten')


    localized_fields = '__all__'


# Default value for salesman
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(gwagen1Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields["verk_num"].initial = benutzer.objects.get(flag_default=True)

    gr = request.user.groups.values_list('name', flat=True)
    if gr:   
        self.fields['km_stand'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using class based views?

If so, in the corresponding view add:

```
def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super(GwagenView, self).get_form_kwargs()  # change to view name

    return dict(kwargs, groups=self.request.user.groups.values_list('name', flat=True))
```

then change the init of the form to:

```
def __init__(self, groups, *args, **kwargs):
    super(gwagen1Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields["verk_num"].initial = benutzer.objects.get(flag_default=True)

    if groups:   
        self.fields['km_stand'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
```

Comment: No I did not use class based views.
The function in views.py starts with:
def new(request):

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Class Based Views (CBVs) then passing an extra argument in the form constructor (e.g. in `get_forms_class`) or in `form_class` will not work, as `<form> object is not callable` will be shown.

The solution for CBVs is to use `get_form_kwargs` to pass the `user` object to `MyForm`:

views.py:

```
form_class = MyForm

# Sending user object to the form, to verify which fields to display/remove (depending on group)
def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super(MyView, self).get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs.update({'user': self.request.user})
    return kwargs
```

forms.py:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')  # To get request.user. Do not use kwargs.pop('user', None) due to potential security hole

        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # If the user does not belong to a certain group, remove the field
        if not self.user.groups.filter(name__iexact='mygroup').exists():
            del self.fields['confidential']
```

Answer (score 0):

No I did not use class based Views:
I found the solution, also valid for function based views.
The user group could be retrieved in the view.py and assigned to the form:

```
gr = request.user.groups.values_list('name', flat=False)
...
form = gwagen1Form(gr, request.POST)

if form.is_valid():
    (do something)
else:
    form = gwagen1Form(gr)
```

In the form.py the init method will retrieve the user groups:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(gwagen1Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields["verk_num"].initial = benutzer.objects.get(flag_default=True)

    # Rolle einlesen
    gr = Group()
    if gr:
        self.fields['km_stand'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
```